# Override LicensePage title?

Tags: flutter, localization

Is it possible to override/change the title in the about view LicensePage which is set with

> MaterialLocalizations.of(context).licensesPageTitle

(Flutter SDK about.dart line 433)

Maybe with a localizationOverride or the localizationsDelegates property in the MaterialApp Widget?

Comment: Have you tried to just put "licensesPageTitle" in your own .arb files?

Comment: yes.. but not working

Comment: OK,  but then please try what you suggest yourself by subclassing DefaultMaterialLocalizations like this: 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/localizationsDelegates.html

Comment: not working too :-(